# How Intel 8085 actually performs a subtraction with previous borrow?

Tags: assembly, microprocessors, 8085, carryflag

My understanding is that in order to evaluate `X - Y - borrow`, we can either perfrom `X - (Y + borrow)` or `(X - Y) - borrow`. Examples in the textbooks depicts the former approach.   In that case, what will happen is the subtrahend (`Y`) is `FFH` and borrow is set (to 1)?

I tried the following code in GNUSim8085 (http://gnusim8085.srid.ca/) which shows a wrong answer (`CY` flag is not set). Is it an implementation issue of GNUSim8085 or this actually happens in physical Intel 8085 chip due to the overflow?

```
STC
MVI A,0FFH
SBI 0FFH
HLT
```

Whereas, the next code gives the correct answer (`A = FFH, CY=1`) as expected.

```
STC
MVI A,00H
SBI 00H
hlt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My understanding is that in order to evaluate `X - Y - borrow`, we can either perfrom `X - (Y + borrow)` or `(X - Y) - borrow`.

Typically, real CPUs do not perform two operations, but they use an ALU that uses "full adder-subtractors". These circuits perform a subtraction with borrow in one operation.

Typically, there is one circuit for each bit (e.g. 8 circuits for an 8-bit subtraction).

The circuit calculating the carry flag also calculates the upper bit (bit 7) of the result; it takes the upper bits (bit 7) of both numbers and an internal flag (which can be 0 or 1) as input. It has no other information!

We calculate `90h-80h`: The result is `10h` or `0Fh` (depending on the former state of the carry flag) and carry is clear. This means that the circuit will calculate `0` as upper bit of the result and clear carry if the upper bits of both input numbers are `1` and the "internal flag" has a certain state (0 or 1).

We calculate `80h-90h`: The result is `0F0h` or `0EFh` and carry is set. This means that the circuit will calculate `1` as upper bit of the result and set carry if the upper bits of both input numbers are `1` and the "internal flag" has the other state.

Calculating `0FFh-0FFh`, the upper bits of both input values also set to `1`. This means: Depending on the "internal flag", the circuit will either set the upper bit of the output to `0` and clear carry, or set the upper bit of the output to `1` and set carry.

So a result of `A=0xFFh` and `CY=0` is not possible.

> Is it an implementation issue of GNUSim8085 or this actually happens in physical Intel 8085 chip due to the overflow?

There are CPUs that do not use a "full-adder" in the lowest bit to calculate a subtraction with borrow.

However, I doubt that the 8085 is one of those CPUs.

Having a look at the [source code of GNUSim8085](https://github.com/GNUSim8085/GNUSim8085/blob/master/src/8085-instructions.c), you'll see comments like this (this one is taken from the function that performs `SBI`):

```
  /* I'm not sure abt the new code
   * Old code:
```

Reading such comments, I think that there are still some bugs in that emulator.

**EDIT**

> If someone having an actual 8085 kit ...

A result of `CY=0` would definitely be a bug!

Why? Because a subtraction of a 32-bit constant from a 32-bit number would lead to the wrong result:

```
1000FF00h - 0FF01h = 0FFFFFFFh  (if CY=1 in your example)
1000FF00h - 0FF01h = 1000FFFFh  (if CY=0 in your example)
```

If Intel really produced some (buggy) 8085 ICs resulting in `CY=0`, Intel would have corrected this bug in ICs produced later!

So you will definitely find real 8085 ICs resulting in `CY=1`, while it is pure speculation that there might *also* be (buggy) ICs resulting in `CY=0`.

By the way: Using the 8085 simulator ["sim8085"](https://www.sim8085.com/), your example results in `CY=1`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But I'm still curious about the actual implementation of `SBB' or `SBI' in 8085. If someone having an actual 8085 kit would be kind enough to try it out, let me know your findings :)

Answer (score 2):

x86 was [designed for 8080 asm source to be mostly 1:1 translatable to 8086](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6500/the-start-of-x86-intel-8080-vs-intel-8086/6501#6501)), so it's likely that 8080 / 8085 work the same way as 8086.

In x86 `sbb` propagates a borrow the way you'd expect mathematically, in a way that's useful for extended precision.  e.g. `FF - FF - 1` does have a borrow output (CF=1), just like working by hand in decimal `9 - 9` with an incoming borrow of 1.

Really `X - (Y + borrow)` and `(X - Y) - borrow` are equivalent, you just need to avoid truncating `Y+borrow` to 8-bit (or save the carry-out from it) if you do it that way.  In both cases, you need to set the borrow output if *either* operation wraps.

(Also, if 8080 / 8085 didn't work that way, it sounds like a bug that would make it unusable for subtracting uint32_t for example without branching to special-case that.)

---

So (unless 8085 had a hardware bug or insane design), that's a simulator bug: I'd guess it needs to use a wider intermediate type, or check for wrapping on both the `A -= src` and `A -= carry` steps.  (Or check for wrapping in the `src + carry` step if it does that first: that means the correct sum is 0x100, larger than any possible 8-bit value.)

C doesn't expose add-with-carry or sub-with-borrow operations, and it's very easy to get it wrong for the general case of carry in and out. (And hard to write efficiently compared to asm.)

---

Fun fact: a recent 6502 question about a possibly-buggy emulator was I think running into a similar emulator bug: [6502 assembly: carry result in 16bit subtraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67663261/6502-assembly-carry-result-in-16bit-subtraction).  One answer even had the branchy work-around which seemed to be necessary on their broken emulator.  (6502 doesn't have sub-without-borrow, and it treats its carry flag as a not-borrow.  So to do a normal subtract, you have to SEC (set carry) then SBC.  Unlike 8080 / 8085 and x86 where the carry flag is set where there *is* a borrow output.

Comment: (Martin's explanation in terms of a full-adder ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)#Full_adder)) makes more sense for CPU internals than my attempt to describe it in terms of two separate operations; that's just how you might emulate it in a language like C without ADC / SBB.)